# Can you use PySpark instead of Glue PySpark in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I find Glue PySpark has it's own little twist to everything like is 'select' is 'select_fields' in Glue PySpark. How can I use spark instead of the Glue version?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `SparkSession` directly instead of the `GlueContext` wrapper:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
gc = GlueContext(sc.getOrCreate())
spark = gc.spark_session

df = spark.read.format(...).load(...)

df.select("*").show()
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of using a spark dataframe over using the glue dynamic frame?

Comment: Glue supports a dynamic schema that can be resolved, Spark Dataframe schemas need to be defined upfront.